# AJAX event in Yii

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii

How can I attach an action to a checkbox or a select, that will be executed every time I click the checkbox or select the option?
I need this to perform an AJAX request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using [CHtml::checkBox()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#checkBox-detail) to generate the checkbox, an example would be:

```
CHtml::checkBox($name, false, array ('ajax'=>array(
                                        'type'=> 'POST',
                                        'url' => $url,
                                        'success'=> 'function(data) {
                                                        // callback function code here
                                                     }'
                )))
```

[Details about the Yii ajax array](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajax-detail)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
//code for ajax request
});
```

in the code for ajax request, if you want to know whether the checkbox is checked, use `$(this).is(':checked')`

Comment: And how can I tight this with Yii ajax methods?

Comment: IMHO it isn't convenient to use such (as in your question) Yii methods in serious systems. Yii is good at validating, but complicated JS-behavior should be developed in JS separetely, using only IDs (or something like this) for keeping linkage.